# Can multithreading be used to make this matrix-vector multiplication algorithm more efficient?

Tags: java, multithreading

For a program that I am making, I want to implement my own matrix-vector multiplication algorithm.  This is the code for it.

```
static <T extends List<Double>> List<Double> matrixVectorMulti(List<T> matrix, List<Double> vector) {
    List<Double> output = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int row = 0; row < matrix.size(); row++) {
        double sum = 0;
        for (int column = 0; column < vector.size(); column++) {
            sum += matrix.get(row).get(column) * vector.get(column);
        }

        output.add(sum);
    }

    return output;
}
```

Is it possible to improve the performance of the algorithm using multithreading or is my algorithm more efficient.  Also, it would be helpful if you could provide me with sample code for an implementation with multithreading.

Note: That a list of lists is being used to model a matrix and a list is being used to model a vector.

Comment: Do you have sample input/output data? Since this is CPU intensive activity, you can implement parallel execution logic. Let's say you have two CPU cores (```Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()```), you can have two threads doing the calculation ... one for row = 0 to matrix.size()/2 and another for remaining rows. You may need to have multiple ```output``` and merge the results.

Comment: To make your code run with multiple threads, you need to find a way to safely divide the problem up. Looking at your code, it seems like the work in the inner `for` loop could be sent to a separate thread. For example, if you have 10 rows, then you would have 10 threads, each calculating a separate `sum` value for each row of data. Then your main `matrixVectorMulti` method would wait for each thread to complete and capture each `sum` value, add them all up, and return that final value as `output`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether multi-threading will improve the performance or not will really depend on many factors

- How much data is present in `matrix`
- How many processes the (virtual) machine has
- the kind of work load (CPU intensive, IO bound)
- many other factors

The use case you have is CPU intensive (multiplication with least IO). Assuming that `matrix` is huge, you may get some level benefit by implementing multi-threading.

Below is one version of multi-threading which makes benefit of parallel processing (number of threads almost equivalent to number of processors available for processing).

Remember that there are other ways to improve performance too ... like initializing `output` ArrayList with matrix size etc.

*Note*: The performance statistics calculated below is not a scientific way ... it just an informal way of calculating. The code is not tested fully. But it can give you the idea.

```
package my.package;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class MatrixMultiplication {

    public List<Double> matrixVectorMulti(List<List<Double>> matrix, List<Double> vector) {
        List<Double> output = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int row = 0; row < matrix.size(); row++) {
            double sum = 0;
            for (int column = 0; column < vector.size(); column++) {
                sum += matrix.get(row).get(column) * vector.get(column);
            }
            output.add(sum);
        }
        return output;
    }

    static List<List<Double>> initializeMatrix(int matrix_size) {
        List<List<Double>> matrix = new ArrayList<>();
        int rangeMin = 100;
        int rangeMax = 200;

        for (int i=0; i<matrix_size; i++) {
            List<Double> row = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int j=0; j<matrix_size; j++) {
                row.add(rangeMin + (rangeMax-rangeMin) * new Random().nextDouble());
            }
            matrix.add(row);
        }

        return matrix;
    }

    static List<Double> initializeVector(int matrix_size) {
        List<Double> vector = new ArrayList<>();
        int rangeMin = 100;
        int rangeMax = 200;

        for (int j=0; j<matrix_size; j++) {
            vector.add(rangeMin + (rangeMax-rangeMin) * new Random().nextDouble());
        }
        return vector;
    }

    public List<Double> matrixVectorMultiParallel(List<List<Double>> matrix, List<Double> vector) {
        int numOfThreads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        List<Double> result = new ArrayList<>();

        //System.out.println(numOfThreads);
        //System.exit(0);
        int batchSize = matrix.size()/numOfThreads;
        PartialVectorMulti[] partialVectorMultis = new PartialVectorMulti[numOfThreads];

        int rangeStart = 0;
        int rangeEnd = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<numOfThreads; i++) {
            rangeEnd = rangeStart + batchSize-1;

            if (i == numOfThreads-1) {
                partialVectorMultis[i] = new PartialVectorMulti(matrix, rangeStart, matrix.size()-1, vector);
            } else {
                partialVectorMultis[i] = new PartialVectorMulti(matrix, rangeStart, rangeEnd, vector);
            }

            partialVectorMultis[i].start();
            rangeStart = rangeEnd + 1;
        }

        for (int i=0; i<numOfThreads; i++) {
            try {
                partialVectorMultis[i].join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        for (int i=0; i<numOfThreads; i++) {
            result.addAll(partialVectorMultis[i].getPartialResult());
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int matrix_size = 10_000;

        List<List<Double>> matrix = initializeMatrix(matrix_size);
        List<Double> vector = initializeVector(matrix_size);
        List<Double> result;
        List<Double> resultMulti;

        MatrixMultiplication matrixMultiplication = new MatrixMultiplication();

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        result = matrixMultiplication.matrixVectorMulti(matrix, vector);
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("matrixVectorMulti: " + (endTime-startTime) + "milli seconds");

        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        resultMulti = matrixMultiplication.matrixVectorMultiParallel(matrix, vector);
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("matrixVectorMultiParallel: " + (endTime-startTime) + "milli seconds");

    }

    class PartialVectorMulti extends Thread {
        List<List<Double>> matrix;
        List<Double> vector;
        int rowStart;
        int rowEnd;
        List<Double> partialResult = new ArrayList<>();

        public PartialVectorMulti(List<List<Double>> matrix, int rowStart, int rowEnd, List<Double> vector) {
            this.matrix = matrix;
            this.rowStart = rowStart;
            this.rowEnd = rowEnd;
            this.vector = vector;
        }

        public List<Double> getPartialResult() {
            return this.partialResult;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i=rowStart; i<=rowEnd; i++) {
                double sum = 0;
                for (int j=0; j<vector.size(); j++) {
                    sum += matrix.get(i).get(j) * vector.get(j);
                }
                partialResult.add(sum);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using multithreading to make an algorithm efficient involves breaking down the problem into smaller units that can be run in parallel and aggregating the results from each.

To break down your algorithm you could go with a divide and conquer strategy as explained in https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/7d07/110b25ec0009962c3599662a7b6b8e4c528a.pdf
and run each sub-task in its own thread. The overhead of synchronization, however, makes it hardly worth it to implement.

Comment: 'The overhead of synchronization, however, makes it hardly worth it to implement' may not be true in all cases. In this particular question, the task is to do vector multiplication where usually no IO waiting/blocking is involved. If we implement number of threads equivalent to number of processors available (usually number of processors +1 threads) and divide the work in such a way that no synchronization is needed, we can achieve better result.

Comment: A divide & conquer system (fork/join) on a single array would require no explicit synchronization, as per the specification: "*The final action in a thread T1 synchronizes-with any action in another thread T2 that detects that T1 has terminated. - T2 may accomplish this by calling T1.isAlive() or T1.join().*" - from [§17.4.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4)